# How do i set the List of struts 2 through javascript?

Tags: javascript, struts2

I am dynamically add options into select element when a user makes a choice in the previous select element. I am using `struts-html tag` inside JSP page. Can anyone suggest how to do this ?

Let me be more specific, i need to populate a `struts2 tag(s:select list)` using Javascript.

i have three dependent dynamic dropdowns all of them are populating from database so am using Ajax+jquery+Struts2  through action am calling the query to the databae and passing the list to javacript through(Ajax+json) and in javascript am setting the list attribute of the s:select tag to the json

this is what i thought please advise me if am wrong or if there is a better way to do this

Comment: `struts-html tag` are you talking about Struts tag or Struts2 tags?

Comment: I thought you were looking for `<s:doubleselect>` until I read the question on the title. What do you exactly want to do?

Comment: Are you using `struts1` or `struts2` or mixing both? `struts-html tag` belongs to `struts1` and `s:select` belongs to `struts2`.

Comment: What's the actual question? There are plenty of demos that use JS to create select options; are you having a specific problem?

Answer (score 0):

One clear option is to use Struts2 [Doubleselect](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/doubleselect.html). You need to do something like

```
<s:doubleselect label="doubleselect test1" name="menu" list="{'fruit','other'}" doubleName="dishes" doubleList="top == 'fruit' ? {'apple', 'orange'} : {'monkey', 'chicken'}" />
<s:doubleselect label="doubleselect test2" name="menu" list="#{'fruit':'Nice Fruits', 'other':'Other Dishes'}" doubleName="dishes" doubleList="top == 'fruit' ? {'apple', 'orange'} : {'monkey', 'chicken'}" />
```

You can find more example here

- [/struts-2-sdoubleselect-example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-sdoubleselect-example/)

If you don't want to use double select you can use simple S2 select tag with help of Jquery, i am not sure from where you want to fetch the values for the second drop down,if this is from the action class better to use Struts2-JSON plugin which will help you to send data as JSON back to UI and you can always use Jquery's JSON parsing capabilities to parse the JSON and fill the drop down like

```
var formInput='state='+statedata;       
   $.getJSON('search/fillDropDown',formInput,function(data) {
     $("#district  option:first").val("-1").text("Please select a  district");
     $('.result').html('' + data.districts + '');
     $.each(data.districts,function(index, value){
     var districtid = document.getElementById("district");
      var option=new Option(value,value);
         try{
           districtid.add(option);
         }
        catch(e){
        districtid.appendChild(option);
        });
     });
```

In above i am filling another drop down based on the value selected in the first drop down and using JSON plugin to send back list from action as JSON data.